# telnetlib TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, telnet

I am modifying a python script to make changes en masse to a hand full of switches via telnet:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "192.168.1.1"
user = input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("User Name: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("?\n")
tn.write("exit\n")
```

When the script executes I receive a "TypeError: expected an object with the buffer interface" Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: A stack trace showing where that exception originates might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/telnetlib.html?highlight=telnetlib#telnetlib.Telnet.read_until), `read_until`'s specs are (quoting, my emphasis):

> Read until a given **byte** string,
>   expected, is encountered

You're not passing a **byte** string, in Python 3, with e.g.:

```
tn.read_until("User Name: ")
```

Instead, you're passing a **text** string, which in Python 3 means a Unicode string.

So, change this to

```
tn.read_until(b"User Name: ")
```

the `b"..."` form is one way to specify a literal **byte** string.

(Similarly for other such calls of course).

Comment: Is it possible to use this same formatting with a string variable? like:
cmd = "User name: " / tn.read_until(b""cmd)?